# Nodejs api insert or update multiple rows with different objects

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, api

I understood how to make a dynamic insert based on what properties has an object:

```
let job_seeker = {
  username: 'j.smith',
  user_type: 'job_seeker',
  name: 'john smith',
  email: 'j.smith@example.com',
  resume: true,
  resume_date_time: '2109-01-01',
  salary_expectation: 100000
};

let employer = {
  username: 'b.burke',
  user_type: 'employer',
  name: 'betty burke',
  email: 'b.burke@example.com',
  company_name: 'Acme Inc.',
  company_profile: 'http://acme.example.com/about_us/'
};


connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', job_seeker, function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.insertId);
});

connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', employer, function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results.insertId);
});
```

But, what if I have an object like:

```
user_employers = [
 {
  username: 'b.burke',
  user_type: 'employer',
  name: 'betty burke',
  company_profile: 'http://acme.example.com/about_us/'
 },
 {
  username: 'b.burke',
  user_type: 'job_seeker',
  name: 'john smith',
  email: 'j.smith@example.com',
  resume: true,
  resume_date_time: '2109-01-01',
  salary_expectation: 100000 
 },
 // and so on, with dynamic properties
]
```

And i have to make a multiple insert or update with the object user_employers? I have to do a loop of INSERT/UPDATE query, or is there a better way?

Comment: don't save passwords in clear text, that unsecure.

Comment: @nbk please i modified the question, the objects are just examples